# How can I delete AppBar in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I deleted Menu by using theme.

```
components: {
    ...defaultTheme.components,
    RaSidebar: {
        styleOverrides: {
        root: {
           width: 0,
        }
       }
    }
}
```

I want to delete appBar completely. But I cannot find classname which is related to appBar. Can anyone help me?

I tried to do it by using various ways.

1. null

`export const MyLayout = (props: any) => <Layout {...props} menu={Mymenu} appBar={null} appBarAlwaysOn/>;`

It didn't work

2. Appbar styling

```
const appBarStyle = {
      minHeight: 0,
    visibility: 'hidden',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    right: '0',
    zIndex: '-1',
    };
  
    return <AppBar  sx={appBarStyle} />;
```

It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const NoAppBarLayout = styled(Layout)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .RaLayout-appFrame`]: { marginTop: 0 },
}))

const MyAppBar = (props: any) => (<></>)
    
export const MyLayout = (props: any) => <NoAppBarLayout {...props} menu={Mymenu} appBar={MyAppBar} />
```